# No visible @interface for 'AcceptView' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios6

I would be very grateful if you could help me solve the problem, then you
Thanks in advance !

**My question1**

Then if I do not know if I will be able to change UIativity 
I still have other errors. .

My error is: No visible `@interface` for 'AcceptView' declares the selector `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

**My question2**
I do not know how to change my code below connection button

I want to use this code to connect button 
The do?

```
  // partager button
    self.buttonshera = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [self.buttonshera setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonorange.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonshera setAlpha:0.9];
    [self.buttonshera.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.buttonshera setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonshera.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
    [self.buttonshera setTitle:[NSLocalizedString(@"buttonshera", nil) uppercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonshera setFrame:CGRectMake(global.xmargin, ypositionstart + 60, global.bodywidth, 32)];
     [self addSubview:self.buttonshera];

    [buttonshera addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(didSelectShare)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**I want to connect this**

```
#pragma mark - Actions

- (void)didSelectShare:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *activityItems = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *htmlBody = @"<html><body><h1>Customized body</h1></body></html>";

    //  For Mail
    [activityItems addObject:[WHMailActivityItem mailActivityItemWithSelectionHandler:^(MFMailComposeViewController *mailController) {
        [mailController setSubject:@"Hey it's a subject!"];
        [mailController setMessageBody:htmlBody isHTML:YES];
        [mailController addAttachmentData:[htmlBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                 mimeType:@"text/html"
                                 fileName:@"Awesome Attachment.html"];
        mailController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    }]];

    //  For texting
    [activityItems addObject:[WHTextActivityItem textActivityItemWithSelectionHandler:^(MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController) {
        [messageController setBody:@"My super awesome message for texting only!"];
        messageController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    }]];

    //  For everything else
    [activityItems addObject:@"Some boring text that should be copied..."];

    NSArray *activities = (@[
                             [[WHMailActivity alloc] init],
                             [[WHTextActivity alloc] init]   // keep in mind that texting is broken on the simulator...
                             ]);

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                                                     applicationActivities:activities];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = (@[
                                                  UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                  UIActivityTypeMail,
                                                  UIActivityTypeMessage,
                                                  UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                  UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll
                                                  ]);

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

**this it .h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Globales.h"

#import "Tools.h"

@interface AcceptView : UIScrollView
{
    Globales *global;

    UITextView *descriptionView;
    UIButton *startmission;
    UIButton *buttonshera;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextView *descriptionView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *startmission;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *buttonshera;


@end
```

**this it .m**

```
#import "AcceptView.h"
#import "WHMailActivity.h"
#import "WHTextActivity.h"
#import "WHMailActivityItem.h"
#import "WHTextActivityItem.h"

@interface AcceptView ()
@end

@implementation AcceptView

@synthesize startmission=_startmission;
@synthesize buttonshera=_buttonshera;
@synthesize descriptionView=_descriptionView;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        global = [Globales getInstance];

        [self setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [self setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [self setBounces:YES];

        self.descriptionView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        [self.descriptionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.descriptionView setOpaque:NO];
        [self.descriptionView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
        [self.descriptionView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
        [self.descriptionView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

        [self.descriptionView setText:[Globales getInstance].missionSelected.oneDescription];
        [self addSubview:self.descriptionView];

        CGFloat fixedWidth = global.bodywidth;
        CGSize newSize = [self.descriptionView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(global.bodywidth, 1000)];
        CGRect newFrame = self.descriptionView.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x = global.xmargin;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
        self.descriptionView.frame = newFrame;

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(load) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) load
{
    int ypositionstart = self.descriptionView.frame.origin.y + self.descriptionView.frame.size.height + 10;

    // Load pageContent with pageElement
    TcheckitMobileBeanService_missionCustom *mission = global.missionSelected;

    if(mission.onePageContentMain != nil)
    {
        if([mission.onePageContentMain.listPageElement count] > 0){
            for(TcheckitMobileBeanService_pageElement *pageElement in mission.onePageContentMain.listPageElement){
                if([pageElement isKindOfClass:[TcheckitMobileBeanService_pageElementMedia class]]){
                    TcheckitMobileBeanService_pageElementMedia *element = (TcheckitMobileBeanService_pageElementMedia *) pageElement;

                    if(element.oneMedia != nil){
                        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(global.xmargin, ypositionstart, global.bodywidth, 480);
                        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

                        [self performSelector:@selector(loadImageInBackground:withMedia:) withObject:imageView withObject:element.oneMedia];

                        ypositionstart = imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height + 5;
                    }
                }

                if([pageElement isKindOfClass:[TcheckitMobileBeanService_pageElementText class]]){
                    TcheckitMobileBeanService_pageElementText *element = (TcheckitMobileBeanService_pageElementText *) pageElement;

                    if(element.title != nil){
                        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(global.xmargin, ypositionstart, global.bodywidth, 10)];
                        [textView setEditable:NO];
                        [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                        [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
                        [textView setText:element.title];
                        [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                        [textView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
                        [textView setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
                        [self addSubview:textView];

                        CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(global.bodywidth, 10000)];
                        CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
                        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, global.bodywidth), newSize.height);
                        textView.frame = newFrame;

                        ypositionstart = textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height;
                    }

                    if(element.content != nil){
                        UITextView *textViewText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(global.xmargin, ypositionstart, global.bodywidth, 10)];
                        [textViewText setEditable:NO];
                        [textViewText setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                        [textViewText setScrollEnabled:NO];
                        [textViewText setText:element.content];
                        [textViewText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                        [textViewText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
                        [textViewText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
                        [self addSubview:textViewText];

                        CGSize newSize = [textViewText sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(global.bodywidth, 10000)];
                        CGRect newFrame = textViewText.frame;
                        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, global.bodywidth), newSize.height);
                        textViewText.frame = newFrame;

                        ypositionstart = textViewText.frame.origin.y + textViewText.frame.size.height + 5;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // accepte button
    self.startmission = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [self.startmission setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonorange.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.startmission setAlpha:0.9];
    [self.startmission.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.startmission setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.startmission.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
    [self.startmission setTitle:[NSLocalizedString(@"startmission", nil) uppercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.startmission setFrame:CGRectMake(global.xmargin, ypositionstart + 20, global.bodywidth, 32)];
    [self addSubview:self.startmission];

    // partager button
    self.buttonshera = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [self.buttonshera setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonorange.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonshera setAlpha:0.9];
    [self.buttonshera.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.buttonshera setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonshera.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
    [self.buttonshera setTitle:[NSLocalizedString(@"buttonshera", nil) uppercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonshera setFrame:CGRectMake(global.xmargin, ypositionstart + 60, global.bodywidth, 32)];
     [self addSubview:self.buttonshera];

    [buttonshera addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(didSelectShare)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


}

- (void) loadImageInBackground:(UIImageView *)imageView withMedia:(TcheckitMobileBeanService_media *)media
{
    [Tools saveImage:media withSuffixe:@""];
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:media.localPath];
    UIImage *scaledImage = [Tools imageWithImage:originalImage scaledToWidth:global.bodywidth];
    [imageView setImage:scaledImage];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, global.bodywidth, scaledImage.size.height)];
    [self addSubview:imageView];
}







#pragma mark - Actions

- (void)didSelectShare:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *activityItems = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *htmlBody = @"<html><body><h1>Customized body</h1></body></html>";

    //  For Mail
    [activityItems addObject:[WHMailActivityItem mailActivityItemWithSelectionHandler:^(MFMailComposeViewController *mailController) {
        [mailController setSubject:@"Hey it's a subject!"];
        [mailController setMessageBody:htmlBody isHTML:YES];
        [mailController addAttachmentData:[htmlBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                 mimeType:@"text/html"
                                 fileName:@"Awesome Attachment.html"];
        mailController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    }]];

    //  For texting
    [activityItems addObject:[WHTextActivityItem textActivityItemWithSelectionHandler:^(MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController) {
        [messageController setBody:@"My super awesome message for texting only!"];
        messageController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    }]];

    //  For everything else
    [activityItems addObject:@"Some boring text that should be copied..."];

    NSArray *activities = (@[
                             [[WHMailActivity alloc] init],
                             [[WHTextActivity alloc] init]   // keep in mind that texting is broken on the simulator...
                             ]);

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                                                     applicationActivities:activities];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = (@[
                                                  UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                  UIActivityTypeMail,
                                                  UIActivityTypeMessage,
                                                  UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                  UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll
                                                  ]);

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}



@end
```

Comment: to connect the button use  `- (void)didSelectShare` not `- (void)didSelectShare:(id)sender` .tell me if it solved you problem

Comment: @ iDon'tCare So I used (void)didSelectShare not (IBAction)didSelectShare:(id)sender ? But because No visible @interface for 'AcceptView' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'I do not know if I have good or not

Answer (score 2):

`presentViewController:animated:completion:` is a method only for ViewControllers, you are using it for a class of ScrollView(AcceptView) which is not a controller hence the error, if You want to use AcceptView , you would have to load it within a ScrollView as a CustomClass it can't be presented or dismissed.

Comment: @ Ashish Kakkad CE Que je: fais? Verser ScrollView Comme CustomClass, j'écris vantent? Recommencer? Ou CREER UNE NOUVELLE Vue UO lorsque des changements?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know I have just edited the answer. I have not given your answer. @gost0

Comment: @gost0 can u plz comment in english, I can understand what you are saying

Comment: @AshishKakkad im sry ....it google t ... auto ..
so im question it what i do ? for ScrollView as a CustomClass, I write all over again? Or create a new view or where i can changes?

Comment: First Of all I don't see any viewCOntroller in Your Code assuming I assume that You have a Main ViewCOntroller under Which You want to add aScrollView, In order to USe thiscustomise ScrollVIew You need to Create an Instance of it and In your MAinViewCOntrolleer, and den use it bu setting its frame and adding it to your View as a Subview

Comment: @AshishKakkad Do you know this piece of code written so Well?

Comment: You have to use this code for view controller only already said by @Geet